# Trying to geocode an address and getting kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult

Tags: ios, objective-c, clgeocoder

So I am trying to GeoCode an address and when someone types in "asdfsfdsf" it throws an error

```
"kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult"
```

How can I catch the error so it doesn't show an ugly popup (i.e. with the error above) to the user?

```
-(void)geocodePinAddress:(NSString *)address withBlock:(void (^)(CLLocationCoordinate2D coord))block {

CLGeocoder* gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
__block CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

[gc geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    // Check for returned placemarks
    if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
        CLPlacemark* mark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        coord = mark.location.coordinate;

        block(coord);

    }

}];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Here is how you can handle geocoder domain errors :


    if(placemarks.count > 0)
    {
       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
       self.outputLabel.text = placemark.location.description;
    }
    else if (error.domain == kCLErrorDomain)
    {
      switch (error.code)
      {
        case kCLErrorDenied:
           self.outputLabel.text = @"Location Services Denied by User";
           break;
        case kCLErrorNetwork:
           self.outputLabel.text = @"No Network";
           break;
        case kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult:
           self.outputLabel.text = @"No Result Found";
           break;
        default:
           self.outputLabel.text = error.localizedDescription;
           break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but it is still popping up the iOS error. Is there a way to use a try catch block so I can prevent iOS from popping there message?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just show the message if an error occurs?

```
- (void)geocodePinAddress:(NSString *)address withBlock:(void (^)(CLLocationCoordinate2D coord))block {
    CLGeocoder *gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    __block CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

    [gc geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        // if there was some error geocoding
        if (error) {
            // display whatever message you want, however you want, here
            return;
        }

        // Check for returned placemarks
        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark* mark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            coord = mark.location.coordinate;

            block(coord);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I would like to show my own message that helps them understand what they did wrong. The "kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult" doesn't help the user with feedback on what they did wrong.

Comment: Right, so write your own message and show it. Do you know how to use a UIAlertView?

Comment: I know how to show an alertview. I need to know how to prevent the iOS SDK from popping its own. iOS is generating its own pop, I want to prevent it from showing.

Comment: As far as I know, it shouldn't be and I've never seen that before. Are you sure you don't have code anywhere that does this?

Comment: The library I was using was popping it. Thanks.